# What is the best structure for SQLite functions?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, version

I had some question about android and i couldn't find what i want. i will list my questions down. I'll be thankful if you help me.

question:
1- Do we have to check for failure or success of database operation?
2- how much it's possible for a database operations like removing or adding or updating a single item to fail? how about a bit larger operations like extracting total_price in case of a shopping app?
3- what is the best way to do database operations? is it ok to use returned values or we have to use callbacks in case something take time to finish?

extra question:
How versioning works in android? if we want to update our app and release a newer, is changing version number of app in gradle enough to make the newer version to replace with previous one on installation?what about app store installation? what happens when it updates previous version to newer one? does the app going to lose data?

please help me with these question, thanks

Comment: This is not a [specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and much too broad. Each of these should be a separate question (and might not be on topic; see the help).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will try to answer to best of my knowledge. let me know if not clear.

1. You would check that once you make a database call by `try/catch` methods and handle them appropriately.
2. Total price shouldnt be a problem, I have had large Json objects saved in `SQL lite` without an issue, the only problem for me was sending it to next activity which is different issue.
3. You can see examples online, mostly you will create a class that holds your operations and call them in your activity/fragments - [see an example here](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

*Other questions:*
If you want to upgrade your app version number - `versionName` and `versionCode` is enough to upgrade your app, you will not lose any database data or in fact any of the shared preference data. You can read more about `SQLite` versioning [here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-sqlite-database-migration-b9ad47811d34).

Comment: thanks. and is it ok to do multiple  operations one after the another so quickly? in my case, for example when an item is deleted from cart -I store all data of cart in db- i delete item from db and then call another function for deleting services of that item and then i call another function to get total price to show to user. is it possible for these operations to fail?